# suppress warning without changing gcc command line

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I am using a third party system to compile my framework. It uses gcc, and I want to change some flags, in particular I want to suppress the warnings about `-Wshadow`. I am not able to change how the framework call gcc, so I am wondering if there are some global environment variable I can set.

I tried:

```
export LOCAL_CFLAGS=-Wno-shadow
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `CFLAGS` is the *common* variable, but it depends on the build system. You *could* disable the warning from within the code with a `#pragma`. Or change the code to get rid of the warning.

Comment: the problem is that the framework is made by many source files, and I would like to suppress all of them.

Comment: Then it depends entirely on the build system. And since you haven't told us what it is there's not much we can do to help.